# Classpath not correct error

Tags: java, class, jar

I have a directory java which has `asd.jar` file and a `test.java` where I am using the `asd.jar` file.

I added the classpath

```
set classpath=C:\d1\d2\d3\asd.jar
```

since the jar file has sub-directories in it, in the `test.java` file I imported the class file I needed from the sub-directories.

now when I give 
`javac test.java`, I get the following error

```
C:\Users\>javac Read.java
Read.java:63: error: cannot access sample
                    sample.loadBackEnd(listoflists);
                    ^
  bad class file: .\asd\subdir1\subdir2\sample.class

  class file contains wrong class: \asd.subdir1.subdir2.sample.class
   Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
 1 error
```

Comment: Do **not** use the (global) `CLASSPATH` environment variable. Use the `-cp` parameter instead. And `javac` can not be used to compile a source file that is *inside* a jar file.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name:  so how should i compile my java file?Can u give me an example?BTW the .java file is not in the jar file  if thats what you meant

Comment: @Arun: ahe told you how to do it: Use the -cp parameter instead.

Answer (score 0):

Are this sample class in the correct package?
If the class is in asd\subdir1\subdir2 path then the first non-comment line in the .java must be "package asd.subdir1.subdir2;"

Comment: i have directory "dir" which has the .java file and the .jar file. Why will i need a package declaration?